# Запись макросов на python

Tags: python

Мне необходимо создать программу, которая будет записывать нажатия клавиш на клавиатуре, я более чем уверен что кто то ранее такое создавал, если же нет, то можете пожалуйста объяснить как это можно реализовать?

*Если что я в пайтоне полный 0, поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь.*

И да, я знаю что есть модуль `keyboard` и в нем ест функция `record`, но она там работает очень криво, и хотелось бы добиться максимальной точности.